# VS Code issues with html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm having a few issues in VS Code specifically with HTML files.

1. The HTML boilerplate feature is not working (typing '!').
2. On existing html files that have content, the "Open in Browser" feature is no longer shown. I even see my "open-in-browser.default": "Safari" is configured in settings.json.

Not sure what change I might've done that caused this as both features were working fine not too long ago.

Comment: Did you set the document type to HTML first, and after typing `!` hit tab?

Comment: check the emmet extension setting in vscode to make sure if you accidentally excluded some languages or any changes.

Comment: @j08691 yes the document is defined as index.html

Comment: @Mejan currently under "Include Languages" in Emmet I see nothing under there. Do you know if there is a specific key-value pair for html? I tried "vue-html":"html" but no luck there

Comment: For the open in browser extension, I've also uninstalled and re-installed with still no luck

Comment: Update: solved the boilerplate issue, in bottom right corner in vs code, the configured file association was set to Django HTML. Switched it to HTML and boilerplate now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed both issues which were actually connected. For some reason my vs code was identifying .html files as Django files. I went into the settings.json and added the following to ensure .html files would be classified as html files

```html
"files.associations": {
        "*.html": "html"
    },
```

This then allowed the open in browser extension to identify the file as html and enable the open in default browser option along with fixing the boilerplate issue.